# preg_replace regex to match 6 identical characters

Tags: php, html, xml, regex, svg

I have SVG files with fills on paths like so:

```
<path fill="#FFFFFF" ... />
<path fill="#CCCCCC" ... />
<path fill="#DDDDDD" ... />
```

I can reduce file sizes slightly by replacing any fills that are 6 identical characters with 3 of the characters, producing:

```
<path fill="#FFF" ... />
<path fill="#CCC" ... />
<path fill="#DDD" ... />
```

I'm not sure how the regex in my php `preg_replace` would look for this. I imagine it would start like this:

```
$fileContent = preg_replace('/fill="#/','',$fileContent);
```

Note the 6 identical characters can be alphanumeric and could be any color, not just my examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$text = <<<EOT
<path fill="#FFFFFF" ... />
<path fill="#CCCCCC" ... />
<path fill="#DDDDDD" ... />
EOT;

$text = preg_replace('/fill="#(.)\1{5}/', 'fill="#$1$1$1', $text);
print "$text\n";
```

Here `(.)` captures the first character and using backreference `\1` with `{5}` it checks that the next five characters are same or not. If yes, then replace with three `$1` which holds the value from `(.)` used in regex.

Comment: This is a good answer, I would probably use this for the regex `/fill="#([\da-f])\1{5}/i` to only match 0-9 and A-F, case insensitive

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$s = '<path fill="#FFFFFF" ... />';
echo preg_replace('/(fill="#)([0-9A-F])\g{-1}{5}/i', '$1\2\2\2', $s);
//=> <path fill="#FFF" ... />
```

Where `\g{-1}` is back reference to most recent group.

Comment: I never used `\g{-1}` before. Its new to me. Thanks.

Comment: I believe this is PCRE feature, haven't tried it on Javascript though.

Comment: Interesting, read from `\g` already, but not from something like `\g{-1}` thanks for input :) very nice!

Answer (score 1):

Try using [back references](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php), for example:

```
$fileContent = preg_replace('/(fill="#)(.)\2{5}/', '\1\2\2\2', $fileContent);
```

This will match any string like `fill="#XXXXXX` and replace it with a string like `fill="#XXX`.

However, hexadecimal color codes like `#FFCC99` [can also be shortened](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#Shorthand_hexadecimal_form) to `#FC9`. If you'd like to handle that case as well, you can try something like this:

```
$fileContent = preg_replace('/(fill="#)(.)\2(.)\3(.)\4/', '\1\2\3\4', $fileContent);
```

This will match any string like `fill="#XXYYZZ` and replace it with a string like `fill="#XYZ`.

Comment: But I only want to match 6 identical characters like `fill="#FFFFFF"` not things like `fill="#F8F8F8"` or `fill="#FFCCAA"`

Comment: @Coop Well if that's a requirement, see my updated answer for an alternative. BTW, neither of these patterns will match `fill="#F8F8F8"`.

Comment: This seems most reasonable

Answer (score -1):

A quick-and-dirty solution would be:

```
$regex = "/#(0{6}|1{6}|...|E{6}|F{6}/";
```

Not the most elegant solution, but it will get the job done.